# Ticking in my Engine

Tags: honda, noise, civic

I have a 1996 Honda Civic every time I press the gas pedal it makes a clicking noise and when I let up on the gas pedal it stops making the ticking noise. I took it into a shop they said I need to replace my axles but they don't make any noise and they didn't drive it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

you need C/V joints. it is simple as that.